# Displaying data from two parallel sequences on web page in compojure

Tags: for-loop, clojure, sequence, compojure

I am trying to display content of two sequences on web page. First one of them contains name of the picture, and the second one contains URL to the image. The problem's start when I try to iterate through these two lists (using foreach-like for loop) - this result in  either multiple picture names, or multiple pictures (in short, a total mess). Here is example of my page rendering code (sequences are converted to vector using `(vec(flatten (sequence)))` ):

```
    (defn view-output []
  (view-layout
   [:h2 "default images"]


   [:form {:method "post" :action "/"}
     ( for [manganame ["image1" "image2"]]
       [:input {:type "text" :value manganame}]) 

       (for [manga-image["image1URL" "image2URL"]]
         [:img {:src manga-image}[:br] [:br][:br]])  ] ))
```

This code will first display names, then pictures. Can anyone suggest a way for inserting these values next to each other, ot on top of each other (perhaps  table like implementation)

```
                               Image_name1
                               Picture1

                             Image_name2
                               Picture2
```

or

```
                    Image_name1      Image_name2
                      Picture1         Picture2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that the correct code is:

```
(defn view-output []
  (view-layout
    [:h2 "default images"]
    [:form {:method "post" :action "/"}
    (interleave 
      (for [manga-name ["image1" "image2"]]
           [:input {:type "text" :value manga-name}]) 
      (for [manga-image["image1URL" "image2URL"]]
           [:img {:src manga-image}[:br] [:br][:br]]))]))
```

As you want a list of [:input][:img][:input][:img].

My previous answer was returning [:input :img][:input :img]:

```
(defn view-output []
  (view-layout
    [:h2 "default images"]
    [:form {:method "post" :action "/"}
    (for [[manganame manga-img] (map vector ["image1" "image2"] ["image1URL" "image2URL"]))]
      (concat 
         [:input {:type "text" :value manganame}] 
         [:img {:src manga-image} [:br ] [:br ] [:br ]]))]))
```

Comment: Hi dAni, I am getting invalid number of arguments in for loop after executing your code, but number of loop args seem ok to me. Can you check this out?

Comment: Hi Mitke, I think it is fixed now

Comment: `(partition 2 (interleave s1 s2))` is a simple `(map vector s1 s2)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(mapcat (fn [manganame mangaimage]
          [[:input {:type "text" :value manganame}]
           [:img {:src mangaimage}]
           [:br] [:br] [:br]])
        ["image1" "image2"]
        ["image1URL" "image2URL"])
```

gives

```
([:input {:type "text", :value "image1"}]
 [:img {:src "image1URL"}]
 [:br] [:br] [:br]
 [:input {:type "text", :value "image2"}]
 [:img {:src "image2URL"}]
 [:br] [:br] [:br])
```